Is a solution of a linear system $Ax=\tilde{b}$ also a solution of $Ax=b \hspace{2 mm} \text{mod}2$?
Suppose we have a $m\times n$ matrix $A$ and a vector $b$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Suppose that a solution is $x$, i.e. $Ax = b \hspace{2mm} \text{mod}2$. This $x$ is made of ones and zeroes. Now, if we apply normal addition, so not modulo 2, we find a new $\tilde{b} = Ax$. Suppose that, after some optimization process, I find a new solution $x'$ which contains less ones, i.e. at least one component that previously was one, now is zero. We have $Ax'=\tilde{b}$. Does this imply that $Ax'=b\hspace{2mm} \text{mod}2$, i.e is $x'$ also a solution of the initial system modulo 2?

If $Ax \equiv b \pmod 2$ and $\tilde b = Ax$, then it's clear that $\tilde b \equiv b \pmod 2$.
So, $Ax' = \tilde b$ means that
$$
Ax' \equiv \tilde b \equiv b \pmod 2. 
$$
So yes, $x'$ is also a solution to the initial system modulo $2$.

Indeed very simple. Thank you
